# Linking neo4j with other databases

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on a research domain called knowledge managment and i am using neo4j. 
I want to link my neo4j base with other database that requires physical data storage (PostgreSQL, MySQL...). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In general sure, it depends on how you want to set up the linking. 
Perhaps you can detail your use-case more?

Normally people sync data between other datastores and Neo4j e.g. by triggering updates or polling.

For Postgres there is also a [foreign data wrapper](https://github.com/nuko-yokohama/neo4j_fdw).

You can also use an [event-sourced system](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2013/09/05/scaling-writes-in-neo4j/), where data is written to your relational databases and relationships also to Neo4j. ([also](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/ending-discussion-to-my-blog-series-about-cqrs-and-event-sourcing/))